# Altium: Change part designator from Letters to numbers

Tags: schematics, altium

I am creating a new component with several parts in Altium Designer. When I place the component in a schematic page, each part get a unique letter like (IC10A, IC10B, IC10C ... etc). How to change these letters to numbers, like (IC101, IC102, IC103 ...etc)

Comment: Why would you want to do so? It is common practice to use letters to indicate different parts of the same IC, while the number is the same. It would be less readable virtually for anyone...

Comment: I agree with @VladimirCravero . You should keep the letter suffixes. Otherwise the reader of your schematic may be confused because the schematic suggests multiple ICs labeled IC101, IC102, etc, but it's really only one IC. What you are suggesting is just an overall bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via Tools -> Board Level Annotate.

You will need to select $ComponentPrefix$GlobalIndex in the "Annotate Options" screen.

However, this is uncommon for Altium and "Copy room format" might behave erratically, so I wouldn't recommend it.

You can always set custom designators for your physical components. To do this, you will need to compile your schematic (c->r) and in the bottom of your schematic you will then see the name of your compiled sheet, eg. U_IO1, U_IO2, ... Switch to one specific sheet and then double click the designator. This will give you the "Physical Component Properties" screen where you can assign a designator manually as well. Again, not really recommended.